# how to start standalone.bat automatically after installing application?

Tags: java, exe, install4j

I have made exe from install4j tool. but I don't know how to start standalone.bat file after installing the application so that i can start my server automatically without user interaction on windows

Comment: I have used `NSIS` http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page . It is script language for creating installers. It has nice Eclipse editor but may be difficult to start with. You just need invisible wrapper that launches your installer and then bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Installer->Screens & Actions step, open the installer and locate the "Finish" screen.

Then, add a "Run executable or batch" file to that screen and configure your batch file as the executable.